# PHP not returning correct info from MySQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql

Well, basically I am working on a register and login tutorial on youtube. Which is using the old version of PHP, and I have attempted to update the code, however when the PHP query's the database, it does not return what I am expecting it to return.

Basically I am testing that the query works by setting $username to 'euan' which exists in the database, but for some reason it will not return that 'euan' exists.

Init.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
    require 'database/connect.php'; echo '[connect loaded]'; echo ' ';
    require 'functions/users.php'; echo '[users loaded]'; echo ' ';
    require 'functions/general.php'; echo '[general loaded]'; echo ' ';
    $errors = array();
?>
```

Connect.php

```
<?php 
    $connection_error = 'We\'re experiencing connection issues. Come back later.';
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die($connection_error);
    mysqli_select_db($con,'forum') or die($connection_error);
?>
```

Login.php

```
<?php
    include 'core/init.php';
    $username = "euan";
    echo $username; echo ' '; echo ' '; echo ' ';
    if (user_exists($username) === true) {
        echo '[Yeah that exists]';
    } else {
        echo '[Nah thats not there]'; echo ' ';
        echo $username; echo ' ';
    }
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true)  {
            $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password';
        } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
        }
    }
?>
```

users.php

```
<?php
    function user_exists($username) {
        echo $username;
        //$username = sanitize($username);
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = $username");
        return(mysqli_query($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
    }
?>
```

Images of database: (cannot embed due to rep.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAkqS.png

http://i.imgur.com/g1niTB3.png

Comment: You need to read up on variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. `$con` does not exist in your function. And your second call to `mysqli_query` will also fail, you need to check the number of rows from the first query instead. And you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: you have to include `database/connect.php` in your `users.php`..ie `include 'database/connect.php'`

Comment: @Lal I thought that I just had to include it in the script in which user_exists is called? Or is that wrong?

Comment: @Riggster: Nope.  $con does not exist 'inside' the function.  You can either pass it in (the better option) like this: function user_exists($username, $con){
or you can call $con 'globally' (ewww!) like this:
function user_exists($username){
 global $con;
 ....

Comment: And also see the use of quotes that @Avinash recommends below!

Comment: @Lal - that is not quite right.  So long as users.php is included _after_ connect.php, users.php can use whatever is 'in' connect.php.  In this situation, the problem is function-scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your users.php, `$username` should be within `'` quotes like below, so that your query will look like `where username='euan'`

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
```

and change return of function also, use `mysqli_affected_rows($con)==1`

this should solve your problem and `$query` is also not required

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
    echo $username;
    //$username = sanitize($username);
    mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return(mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) ? true : false;
}
?>
```